# chmod is not working on php and I can not write a file!

Tags: php, chmod, fwrite

Hi I want to write in a file with php, but I can not write anything. When I write this test function I got "Cannot change the mode of file deneme" error. How can use chmod and so that I can write into a file thanks for helping..

```
   <?php
        function file_write($filename, $flag, &$content) {
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                if (!is_writable($filename)) {
                    if (!chmod($filename, 0666)) {
                         echo "Cannot change the mode of file ($filename)";
                         exit;
                    };
                }
            }
            if (!$fp = @fopen($filename, $flag)) {
                echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
                exit;
            }
            if (fwrite($fp, $content) === FALSE) {
                echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
                exit;
            }
            if (!fclose($fp)) {
                echo "Cannot close file ($filename)";
                exit;
            }
        } 
$a="osman";  file_write("deneme", "w", &$a); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to php manual and chmod() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php as you need write permissions for that folder/file

Comment: I've already read there, even that test function was taken from that page. but I couldnt find any solution...

Comment: what's your file chmod right now? have you tried to change the chmod

Comment: yes although I  change chmod in terminal, I can not change with php. even safe mode is off but still i can not use chmod:S

Comment: whats your ssh user:group and whats your webserver/php user:group and what are your folder file permissions right now. You can find that out with ls- la filename and ls -la foldername

Answer (score 0):

I guess tha main thing is "The current user is the user under which PHP runs." Can you perform `chmod` on the file you've created via php script?

Comment: I can neither write nor create a file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you looked into [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).